# Using Factless Fact table used as source for Fact Table

Tags: data-warehouse, fact

I have a design for a Property / Occupancy factless fact so I can capture the data for when customers move in and out of properties.

However I am not sure if it is best practice to use this as a source for maybe a occupied flag for my SCD property?

Or a fact table that needs to capture the status of the occupancy?

Please advise :)

Answer (score 0):

I would never (or only in exceptional cases) build a fact table just to provide information to update other tables in your DW. Your source system presumably provides the occupancy information so you can use this to update dimensional attributes, where necessary, as part of your ETL processes